# Can Epilog be used with ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics

This command:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
     Epilog -> {Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {Cos[\[Pi]], Sin[\[Pi]], \[Pi]}}]}]
```

Produces the message:

> Coordinate {0, 0, 0} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you want:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}], 
 Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {Cos[Pi], Sin[Pi], Pi}}]]
 ]
```

[image: plot]

Epilogs are 2D only...

Comment: Was about to write a "hey I know something" comment, until I realized your "Epilogs may be 2D only" was not to [suggest that it is possible](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/maymight/menu.php) but to state that Epilog **only** accepts 2D directives.

Comment: @bobthechemist Oh yes, I can see I wrote that badly. I will disambiguate. Thanks!

Comment: I have used the Show[graphic 1 graphic2] as a work around.  The error message now suggests to me that epilog IS limited to 2D directives.